# SQL Dynamic time line account transaction

Tags: sql-server

i'm trying to perform a chur model withil dynamic time line for each account, my data base is on SQL server so for each costumer i need at least 6 months of transaction behavior, that means i will pick from your last transaction and move backward, that meas from your last transaction i will go back 6 monthts indempendement for each account customer... rgards i will appreciate your help

Comment: Question requires sample data, desired output and the query you have tried........without this first you have to check how to ask question ??

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i cant provide a data table, because off my environment work
i'll try try be clear i have an transaction table with 645784963 lines for all accounts, the questions is rather than fix my date for today i want to make sure that i pick the max(date) for each customer (account level) and move backward 6 months so each customer will have a dynamic 6 months time line